# Update screensaver theme using gconftool-2

Tags: linux, gnome, gconf

How can i update the screensaver theme?

I am using:

```
$sudo gconftool-2 -t --list-type string --set /apps/gnome-screensaver/themes [screensavers-xyz]
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I get an error saying "Don't understand type '--list-type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gconftool-2), try adding a data type after **-t** as well, like this:

`gconftool-2 --type list --list-type string --set /apps/gnome-screensaver/themes '[screensavers-xyz]'`

For example, something like:

`gconftool-2 --type list --list-type string --set /apps/gnome-screensaver/themes '[screensavers-personal-slideshow]'`

or

`gconftool-2 --type list --list-type string --set /apps/gnome-screensaver/themes '[screensavers-cosmos-slideshow]'`

Comment: thanks Karan for the answer. It worked. Also, my screensaver only runs for 5 mins. How can I make it run for X mins?

Comment: @Wasi: Normally after 5 mins. or so of inactivity, the screen blanks and goes into power-saving mode, which is a good thing. If you want to modify the timeout, check [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2062608) for instructions.